# What is the goal of template_preprocess_page(&$variables)?

Tags: theming, users

I am trying to modify the login and register page drupal 7 but i actually don't understand what is the goal of template_preprocess_page(&$variables) ... Someone can give me a better explanation of that ?

Answer (score 2):

It is an entry point in your theme or module that allows you to modify or add template variables before the page (or applicable item) is rendered. This hook affects any page*.tpl.php files.

Similarly, `template_preprocess_node` is the same, but for node templates.

Example:

I need to change existing variable `foo`:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  // $foo used to be 'Old Value'
  $variables['foo'] = 'New Value';
}
```

I need to add new variable:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  // $baz does not yet exist
  $variables['baz'] = 'Baz!';
}
```

These are injected into the template, then they can be rendered with `render` or printed:

`page.tpl.php`:

```
<?php print $foo; ?>
<?php print $baz; ?>
```

This is because `$variables` are passed by reference (note the **&** symbol) which allows you to modify the array.

Comment: Well, there are template suggestions (file name patterns) you have to adhere to. Of course, you can create your own too - but you have to define them first.

Comment: Ah ok i understand, so if i want to modify login page : I create a page-user-login.tpl file; In template.php i modify the $var with a function mytheme_preprocess_user_login(&$variables); and i call my form in user-login.tpl ? It is not better to do a hook-form-alter in a module ? Or can i just modify the login form without preprocess function ? Thank you for your help !

Comment: Depends, if you are altering a form, form alter is the only option. If you are altering template variables, you want preprocess hooks.

Comment: I am a little lost about what method i need to use. In this post, they seems to modify a form without using form_alter : https://www.drupal.org/node/1152816

Comment: No, thats all preprocessing particular page hooks, and adding variables surrounding the form. I wouldn't advise printing form array items piecemeal, because it is very easy to miss critical parts like the form token and other items that make forms actually work.

Comment: Ok that is really good to know. I will then create a module to completly modify the login and register form. You know if it is possible to modify an entire page ? Or i need to create a module to modify form and a tpl to modify the user/login page ? (sorry, some of my questions are maybe stupid, but i really want to do things well).